# online payment process in radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi guys im developing in my own website.every thing works fine.i want to know if i clicks the any one of the radio button that value change correspondingly.can any one please post some code i tried this below code. my website is http:spsmobile.co.uk just check the link
in this page u just go to phone unlock and click make payment you will see the radio button named pay delivery methods
thanks in adv

```
 var total = parseInt($("div.total-text").text().substring(1), 10);
    $("input[name='rmr']").bind('change', function () {
        var amount = 0;
        switch (this.value) {
        case "1":
            amount = 3;
            break;
        case "2":
            amount = 5.5;
            break;
        case "4":
            amount = 10;
            break;
        }
        $("div.total-text").text("£" + (total + amount));
    });
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#primary').bind('change', function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "include/unlock_function.php",
                data: $(this).is(':checked'),
                success: function (theresponse) {}
            }
            }
        };
        }
    }:
```

Comment: How exactly is JSP related to this? Are you running JSP and PHP on the same server? Or are you just confusing JSP with JavaScript?

Comment: OK, you just confused JSP with JavaScript. I've fixed the question tag. I suggest you to revise your question to describe the problem in detail. It isn't clear what needs to be corrected. I also suggest you to write full and formal English sentences. They starts with uppercase and ends with one dot and are written with full words, not in text-speak. This way you will be taken for more serious and thus generate more chance on good answers. See also http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: @BalusC - Please remove the php and mysql tags, as the question seems to be about jquery...

Comment: I think I have seen the same question twice today already, posted by a single user. I also commented on the second one asking the OP not to repost but edit. This is exactly the same question with some code. It is ok if you(the OP) are different, but if you are the same person, please stop doing this.

Comment: @dheerosaur I've seen this a few times in the past couple of days as well - all different users too. *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are asking for, but I suggest you start using Firebug to catch errors and debug your code better.
Suppose your code is complete, then you have a lot of errors (brackets..etc) I suggest using netbeans (for example) and not a notepad:

```
var total = parseInt($("div.total-text").text().substring(1), 10);
$("input[name='rmr']").bind('change', function () {
    var amount = 0;
    switch (this.value) {
    case "1":
        amount = 3;
        break;
    case "2":
        amount = 5.5;
        break;
    case "4":
        amount = 10;
        break;
    }
    $("div.total-text").text("£" + (total + amount));
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#primary').bind('change', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "include/unlock_function.php",
            data: $(this).is(':checked'),
            success: function (theresponse) {}
        });
    });
});
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/ulado4/2) for the rmr radio.